# Evaluating iterated sine function

Tags: recurrence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f(x,1)=\sin(x)$ and $f(x,i)=f(\sin(x),i-1)$ ($f$ is the iterated sine function). For arbitrary $N$,$x_0$, how quickly can $f(x_0,N)$ be computed?

Answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66991/series-expansion-for-iterated-function) discusses Carleman-Matrix method. Is this method precise for very big $N$?